# SQL get the closest two rows within duplicate rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have following table

```
ID   Name      Stage
1    A           1      
1    B           2                 
1    C           3  
1    A           4
1    N           5
1    B           6
1    J           7 
1    C           8
1    D           9
1    E           10
```

I need output as below  with parameters `A and N` need to select closest rows where difference between stage is smallest

```
   ID   Name      Stage
    1    A           4      
    1    N           5
```

**I need to select rows where difference between stage is smallest**

Comment: can u explain more?
why the `id` is the same?

Comment: not clear, can you add some SQL commands you tried?

Comment: Basically all records belong to one object only

Comment: @wpcoder I need to select rows where difference between stage is smallest, will post my current half baked SP in some time

Comment: @Salman sorry two closest rows only

Comment: or one combination row anything will do

Comment: A stage 4 isnt any closer to N stage 5 than C stage 3... do you only want the closest value with closest stage greater than current record's stage?

Comment: that's right, but it doesn't make his question wrong. this query has multiple answer @DanielMachet

Comment: @DanielMachet  i will send A and N as paramter i need closest rows see there are two A and one N , difference between in 1 combination is 4 and another is 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query can make use of an index on `(name, stage)` efficiently:

```
WITH cte AS (
   SELECT TOP 1
          a.id AS a_id, a.name AS a_name, a.stage AS a_stage
        , n.id AS n_id, n.name AS n_name, n.stage AS n_stage
   FROM   tbl a
   CROSS  APPLY  (
      SELECT TOP 1 *, stage - a.stage AS diff
      FROM   tbl  
      WHERE  name = 'N'
      AND    stage >= a.stage
      ORDER  BY stage

      UNION ALL
      SELECT TOP 1 *, a.stage - stage AS diff
      FROM   tbl  
      WHERE  name = 'N'
      AND    stage < a.stage
      ORDER  BY stage DESC
      ) n
   WHERE  a.name = 'A'
   ORDER  BY diff
   )
SELECT a_id AS id, a_name AS name, a_stage AS stage FROM cte
UNION ALL
SELECT n_id, n_name, n_stage FROM cte;
```

SQL Server uses `CROSS APPLY` in place of standard-SQL `LATERAL`.

In case of ties (equal difference) the winner is arbitrary, unless you add more `ORDER BY` expressions as tiebreaker.

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=9037358235b80ab874bfc3c719ae0841)*

Comment: Thank you so much this query works but takes time to execute, i will just test and mark as answer shortly

Answer (score 1):

This solution works, if u know the minimum difference is always 1

```
    SELECT * 
    FROM myTable as a
    CROSS JOIN myTable as b
    where a.stage-b.stage=1;


     a.ID   a.Name      a.Stage  b.ID   b.Name      b.Stage
        1    A           4        1       N             5
```

---

Or simpler if u don't know the minimum

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable as a
    CROSS JOIN myTable as b
where a.stage-b.stage in (SELECT min (a.stage-b.stage) 
    FROM myTable as a
    CROSS JOIN myTable as b)
```

Comment: it says Invalid column name 'dif'. but this is somelike what i am looking for

Comment: This computes the difference between *any* rows, not just between two given names like 'A' and 'N'. Plus, you would have to replace `dif` with the expression `a.stage-b.stage`.